# Spring как сделать один контроллер для всех страниц не перекрывая static?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Собственно есть конфигурация вида:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/extjs/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login/restore").anonymous()
        .antMatchers("/login/reg").anonymous()
        .antMatchers("/login/auth").anonymous()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

И есть контроллер:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/**")
public class Index {
    @GetMapping
    public String get() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Сейчас получается так, что из-за роутинга `@RequestMapping("/**")` перекрывается роутинг для static файлов. Как этого избежать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537877/spring-serving-static-content-while-having-wildcard-controller-route

Comment: Что Вы хотите конкретно увидеть в этом решении? Отрисовку компонентов? Возврат шаблонной страницы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в конфигурацию следующее:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/extjs/**");
}
```

А вот эту часть можно убрать :

```
.antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/extjs/**").permitAll()
```

Comment: Половина запросов cancelled, половина открывают не файлы, а контроллер.  Причем cancelled есть и с css файлами и с extjs.

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1.**

Разместить все ресурсы в подпапках и добавить ResourceHandler с высоким приоритетом:

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/images/");
    }
}
```

**Вариант 2.**

Вручную проверить существование ресурса. *(Не знаю как это скажется на производительности)*

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @GetMapping("/**")
    @ResponseBody
    public Object get(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("/static" + request.getRequestURI());
        if (resource.exists()) {
            return resource;
        }
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
}
```

**Вариант 3.**

Если вы делаете одностраничное приложение, то, возможно, будет проще перечислить все возможные пути:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @GetMapping({"/page1/**", "/page2/**", "/page3/**"})
    public String get() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понятен смысл данного решения. Но все же, если Вы хотите конкретно рисовать компоненты в самой вьюхе и передавать в аргументы блоки (соответственно на фронте уже парсить их), то скудное решение в виде абстракции/наследования и возврат для любого реквеста в функцию `commonPage`
Имхо

```
public abstract class AbstractController {
    public String commonPage(ModelMap map) {
        map.addAttribute("commonObject", new Object());
        .....
        map.addAttribute("page", "/templates/someHtmlOrJsp.html|.jsp");
        .....
        return "index";
    }
}
```

SampleController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class SampleController extends AbstractController {
    @RequestMapping(method = {GET, HEAD})
    public String index(ModelMap map) {
        map.addAttribute("somePageObject", new Object());
        ....
        return commonPage(map);
    }
}
```